# Position elements without overlap

Tags: algorithm, math, physics, overlap

I have a number of rectangular elements that I want to position in a 2D space. I calculate an ideal position for each element. Now my problem is that many elements overlap as very often the ideal positions are concentrated in one region. I want to avoid overlap as much as possible (doesn't have to be perfect, though). How can I do this?

I've heard physics simulations are suitable for this - is that correct? And can anyone provide an example/tutorial?

By the way: I'm using XNA, if you know any .NET library that does exactly this job - tell me!

Comment: Let me try to clarify; you have an 'ideal position' algorithm already; you want to find the solution to moving objects *away* from their 'ideal position' in a way so that there is no overlap?

Comment: That's right. What I want to create is a visualization. The ideal position is determined by several properties of the elements' underlying records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box2D is a widly used (free) physics library that can achieve the needed task: [Link](http://box2dxna.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

One way the physics engine can be used:

Put positive electric charges (or some kind of repulsive force) on each rectangles and simulate the forces and movements. Also, as Eyal was kind enough to point out, you also need some attractive forces to keep them from drifting away. This can be modelled by springs (again as Eyal points out). They will *hopefully* end up in some sort of equilibrium which might involve non-overlapping rectangles.

I believe similar ideas (force based heuristics) are used in determining nice looking layouts of graphs (the nodes and edges one).

Disclaimer: I haven't used this myself.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Moron: I think that using only repulsive force will not end up in equilibrium. The force based algorithm for drawing graphs, for example, use both a repulsive force and an attractive force between the nodes (the first simulating electrical charges of the same sign, and the second simulating springs).

Comment: @Eyal: Thanks, I will edit the answer. And my duh! Unless we contain the rectangles, repulsive forces will just cause them to drift away :-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. that sounds good. I just have to understand how I can do this with the Box2D library @tur1ng posted.

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm that you are looking for is [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). XNA has its own [lerp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.lerp.aspx) function.

Comment: That function is actually quite useful for me in another part of the project - but could you explain how exactly I can use it to solve the problem I mentioned?

Comment: @eWolf, I've used the algorithm to properly distribute a bar graph over a specified pixel width. The algorithm allows you to properly size and space out objects so that the objects take up the whole space, without overlap.